# Чем заменить тег br?

Tags: html, css

Чем можно заменить тег `<br>`, чтобы не повторять его множество раз в html разметке?

Comment: смотря где его используете, как вариант задавать расстояние через css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

например:

```
 <p/>
```

или:

```
<div style="clear:both" />
```

Comment: <p/> - покажите ссылку откуда такое чудо. Эти теги должны закрываться.

Comment: это обозначение пустой ноды в XML XHTML

вместо пустого <p></p> или <li><li/>

можем написать тег и сразу его закрыть с меньшим количеством символов
<p/> или <li/>

кстати <br> желательно писать <br/> тоже касается и других ординарных тегов

http://xhtml.ru/2005/04/01/html-xhtml-xml/

Comment: сейчас лучше использовать доктайп HTML5 - при этом <p/> - это будет не валидно

Comment: По спецификации `html5` некоторые `html` тэги могут быть сразу закрытими [https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags], но `<p>` в них не входит. Если хотите чтобы документ мог парсится ещё и как XHTML то нужно ясно писать `</p>`.

Answer (score 6):

`div`'ом фиксированный высоты.
Внутри него нужен только 1 `<br>`, а можно и не `<br>`, а скажем `&nbsp;` — просто чтобы `div` самопроизвольно не удалился.

Comment: это как же div самопроизвольно удалится? месье знает толк в извращениях встроенных редакторов джумлы и вордпресс?)))

Comment: это не зависит от CMS. Это зависит от браузера: создай в блокноте пустой хтмл и в боди закинь пустой див с указанием высоты в 100 пикселей. А потом проверь в разных браузерах его размер.

Comment: @Andrew, и в каких же он будет другим?

Comment: не помню точно. Когда я этот тест проводил, у меня вродь была проблема с хромом такая. Но это было года 3 назад. Проверь все браузеры. Давно было, потому точно не скажу. Но высота точно оставалась в каком-то браузере нулевой независимо от указанной. Пока не вставить  &nbsp; внутрь дива.

Comment: @Andrew, https://jsfiddle.net/fquc1p67/ - Даже IE 11-ой версии показал div в 400xp в высоту. Подскажите такой такой диковинный браузер вы пользовали, который не понимает CSS параметр hight для блоков div и, как вы утверждали, самопроизвольно удаляет их или "схлапывает", на крайний случай, их?

Answer (score 3):

Вам что нужно, отступы? все решается стилями в css и классами там же. Слышали про классы?))
Тегам **p** присвойте один отступ, блокам **div** - другой и везде можно применять классы, зачем пихаете этот мусор, не понятно, тем более, как видно, пихаете не в текст, а в разметку, т.е. изначально губите шаблон.
Часто вижу в приносимых на очеловечивание шаблонах упомянутый тег **br**: поминаю неким словом предыдущего верстальщика, вооружаюсь топором и надфилем, и открываю стилевой файл...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос частый среди новичков, а развёрнутого ответа с рабочими примерами видеть не доводилось. Попробую дать таковой сам.

---

### 1. Разделение абзацев

Положим, необходимо отделить один блок текста от другого.

#### 1. C использованием `<br>`

Два блока текста отделяются посредством `<br><br>`.

```html
<body>
    От колумеллы завернул на срисованный с топографической карты мост греческого носа, разогнался и очутился перед ширью чела, усеянной едва приметными эфемеридами. Отдельно торчащие волоски обрамляли пушистый каскад, вуалью из тончайшей паутинки прикрывая внитие в пробор посередине. Нежная кожа руки, несомненно, ароматнее цветов на иконах ниже... Тщательно протёр зенки: стоп, я не Виктор Кандинский во власти дебютной галлюцинации.
    <br><br>
    Однако стоило попутчице с ближнего ко входу сидения подвинуть локоть, как проступили пухленькие губки, слабо напоминающие Божьи. Они принадлежали высокой мощной путешественнице с неуклюжей широкой походкой, непринуждённо закинувшей наверх свой и подруги громадные рюкзаки. Помимо профиля с закрытыми очами в ней не содержалось ни на йоту от Эталона, чего, правда, вполне хватало для любования. Тут осенило, как провести эту обездвиживающую и притупляющую ночь.
</body>
```

#### 2. Без использования `<br>`

Каждый из двух блоков текста заключается в тег `<p></p>`.

```html
<body>
    <p>От колумеллы завернул на срисованный с топографической карты мост греческого носа, разогнался и очутился перед ширью чела, усеянной едва приметными эфемеридами. Отдельно торчащие волоски обрамляли пушистый каскад, вуалью из тончайшей паутинки прикрывая внитие в пробор посередине. Нежная кожа руки, несомненно, ароматнее цветов на иконах ниже... Тщательно протёр зенки: стоп, я не Виктор Кандинский во власти дебютной галлюцинации.</p>
    <p>Однако стоило попутчице с ближнего ко входу сидения подвинуть локоть, как проступили пухленькие губки, слабо напоминающие Божьи. Они принадлежали высокой мощной путешественнице с неуклюжей широкой походкой, непринуждённо закинувшей наверх свой и подруги громадные рюкзаки. Помимо профиля с закрытыми очами в ней не содержалось ни на йоту от Эталона, чего, правда, вполне хватало для любования. Тут осенило, как провести эту обездвиживающую и притупляющую ночь.</p>
</body>
```

#### 3. Компиляция Markdown в HTML.

Оборачивание вручную каждого блока текста может занять достаточно продолжительное время. Однако есть средства, облегчающие задачу, как то использование разметки [**Markdown**](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), — [**не только по моему мнению**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-future-of-markdown/) много удобнее нативного HTML — с последующей конвертацией в HTML. Для создания отступа в Markdown достаточно создать между блоками текста пустую строку:

```markdown
От колумеллы завернул на срисованный с топографической карты мост греческого носа, разогнался и очутился перед ширью чела, усеянной едва приметными эфемеридами. Отдельно торчащие волоски обрамляли пушистый каскад, вуалью из тончайшей паутинки прикрывая внитие в пробор посередине. Нежная кожа руки, несомненно, ароматнее цветов на иконах ниже... Тщательно протёр зенки: стоп, я не Виктор Кандинский во власти дебютной галлюцинации.

Однако стоило попутчице с ближнего ко входу сидения подвинуть локоть, как проступили пухленькие губки, слабо напоминающие Божьи. Они принадлежали высокой мощной путешественнице с неуклюжей широкой походкой, непринуждённо закинувшей наверх свой и подруги громадные рюкзаки. Помимо профиля с закрытыми очами в ней не содержалось ни на йоту от Эталона, чего, правда, вполне хватало для любования. Тут осенило, как провести эту обездвиживающую и притупляющую ночь.
```

Как видно, результаты компиляции для различных парсеров Markdown в HTML [**имеют небольшие различия**](http://mcaf.ee/p9a8ih), но везде блоки текста оборачиваются в тег `<p></p>` и не используется `<br>`.

---

### 2. Отступы

Допустим, в декоративных целях требуются множество пустых линий между двумя элементами.

#### 1. C использованием `<br>`

Отделяем друг от друга текст и изображение.

```html
<head>
    <style>
    #SashaDiv {
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: blueviolet;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="SashaDiv">Саша и Её кот</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c629230/v629230663/17f7f/y31918FBaZs.jpg" height="219" width="320">
</body>
```

#### 2. Без использования `<br>`

```html
<body>
    <style>
    #SashaDiv {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 0 0 10rem;
        color: blueviolet;
    }
    </style>
    <div id="SashaDiv">Саша и Её кот</div>
    <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c629230/v629230663/17f7f/y31918FBaZs.jpg" height="219" width="320">
</body>
```

Используется свойство CSS `margin`. Допускается [**использование от одного до четырёх значений `margin`**](https://webref.ru/css/margin#field_css_value), в примере их 3. Первый ноль задаёт отступ от верхнего края элемента, второй — от левого и правого одновременно, третий — от нижнего. Т.е. от блока текста до нижеследующего элемента — иконы — в примере задан отступ, равный `10rem`.

Отступы посредством `margin` корректно работают, если их задать от [**блочных, не инлайновых**](https://webref.ru/course/html-basics/block-inline) элементов.

---

### 3. Дополнительные ссылки

#### 1. Где не стоит использовать `<br>` и причины тому

- [**Is it sometimes bad to use `<BR />`?**](https://www.joedolson.com/2007/01/is-a-br-tag-semantic/)
- [**Is a br tag semantic?**](https://www.joedolson.com/2007/01/is-a-br-tag-semantic/).

#### 2. Использование тега `<br>` в качества разделителя параграфов

- [**Bed and BReakfast markup (B&BR)**](http://tantek.com/log/2002/10.html#L20021022t1432).

#### 3. margin

- [**О свойстве `margin` на сайте Webref.ru**](https://webref.ru/css/margin).

Comment: Так себе ответ. По форме выглядит как развёрнутое подробное описание, а на деле - нет. 1. Стоит описать семантическую разницу между `br` и `p` - хоть на примере со стишком. Потому что это сейчас они в ответе выглядят как абсолютно равноценные варианты, но это не так. Та же ситуация с margin'ом. 2. Зачем тут markdown вообще не понятно. 3. А где собственно один из самых полезных вариантов для введённых пользователем текстов css-свойство `whitespace`??

Comment: Минус ставить не стану - надеюсь, дополнишь.

Comment: Да, ещё. Сниппеты какие-то странные. Не надо в них засовывать всю страницу - лучше просто правильно заполнить блоки для внутренностей body и для css. Ну и я бы их спойлерами сделал, а перед ними описание семантики а также плюсов и минусов соответствующего варианта.

Comment: @Qwertiy, **1.** Вопрос стоял: чем заменить `br`, а не почему тег не рекомендуется использовать. По этому вопросу ограничился ссылками в пункте 3.1. // **2.** а) вопрос и ответ ориентированы прежде на новичков, чтобы показать им о более удобной разметке, дабы не писали на чистом HTML; б) для демонстрации, что парсеры конвертируют в блоки с `p` без использования `br`, что дополнительно наводит на мысли о нежелательности использования `br`.

Comment: **3.** А часто ли используется `white-space` на практике? я лично один случай только припоминаю, когда мне приходилось применить данное свойство. Если действительно часто (а я знаю в CSS куда меньше Вас), неплохо было бы, если б дополнили ответ или написали свой. Спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, по поводу сниппетов: я всё, что не относится к теме вопроса, убрал, только кодировку решил оставить. Здесь в сниппетах её необязательно указывать, но если пользователь захочет потестировать код у себя, то увидит кракозябры вместо кириллических символов.

Comment: 1. html-разметка в сниппете помещается внутрь body самим сниппетом. 2. Пользователь увидит нечто в соответствии с кодировкой, в которой он сохранит файл. Насколько я помню, utf8 - это дефаултный вариант для браузеров.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Вы правы, удалил кодировку из кода: из-за аддона [**Charset Switcher**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/charset-switcher/) страницы не отображались у меня в UTF-8 без указания кодировки. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных *"Вопрос стоял: чем заменить br, а не почему тег не рекомендуется использовать. По этому вопросу ограничился ссылками в пункте 3.1"* То есть по сути для самого главного вы просто кидаете ссылки? Чем полезно содержимое ответа само по себе?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, как поставлена формулировка вопроса, на то и отвечаю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

C помощью CSS. 
После первого параграфа, добавлен дополнительный разрыв.

```css
p::before {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```