# Отступы между строками в списках с произвольно заданными маркерами

Tags: html, css

Как создать список с произвольно заданными маркерами, читал [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/spisok-s-russkimi-bukvami) и [тут](http://samizdam.net/2012/03/%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/). Проблема в том, что при простановке тега `<br />` между элементами списка пропадают маркеры:

```css
 body {
   background: bisque;
   color: crimson;
 }
 ol {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   line-height: 0.5;
 }
 .list {
   list-style-type: none;
 }
 .list li::before {
   margin-right: 10px;
   width: 1em;
   text-align: right;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .list li:nth-child(1)::before {
   content: '4.';
 }
 .list li:nth-child(2)::before {
   content: '14.';
 }
 .list li:nth-child(3)::before {
   content: '7.';
 }
```

```html
<ol class="list">
  <li>Саша Черных</li>
  <br />
  <li>Необыкновенная</li>
  <li>И Единственная</li>
</ol>
```

Если убрать `<br />`, проблем с маркерами нет, но мне нужны отступы между строк.

Чем пытался заменить `<br />`: [другими тегами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/312101/199934), различными *margin*'ами, — отступы и маркеры всё равно не отображаются правильно. Частично помогло применение свойства [*white-space*](https://webref.ru/css/white-space), однако расстояние между элементами списка выходит слишком большим, и с помощью [*margin*](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=469197&msg=4610675) изменить его не получается.

```css
body {
  background: bisque;
  color: crimson;
}
ol {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.list li::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.list li:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: '4.';
}
.list li:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '14.';
}
.list li:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '7.';
}
```

```html
Бессонница ненавистна не сама по себе, а обязательно обуяющей вас с рассветом усталостью, аннигилирующей способности мыслить и радоваться. Натянув капюшон, я старался не отягощать серое вещество размышлениями, уповая сохранить хоть какие-то силы. У поребрика близ палатки шавермы сайд- и фронт-киками всадили в рёбра женщине, на фоне полёта насекомых — вылитых фей — зарядили непосредственно по моему мениску.
  <ol class="list">
    <li>В российских реалиях полноценно это светит исключительно при обладании достаточной суммой на счету. Оптимальный вариант ради горизонтальной доски с ножками и относительного покоя — заплатить за кучу лишних услуг хостелам. В том числе выбравшись из дому: номера общежития на 10—20 обитателей, сдобренного запахом пропавших пельменей и отборным матом. Неужели никому не нравится подыматься спозаранку на службу при бодром расположении духа, что в подлунной тиши не заткнётся орущий телевизор?</li>
    <li>Саша Мечта</li>
    <li>И История</li>
  </ol>
```

Как задать межстрочные отступы?

Comment: br - между li - валидатор будет ругаться - Element br not allowed as child of element ol in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: а разве .list li{margin:15px 0;} - не работает? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/vdrsa0oy/

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо, вроде работает! Да, а почему приходится так изощряться, чтобы задать простые отступы? В списках с обычными маркерами или, допустим, `<ol type="I">` у меня не возникало этой проблемы.

Comment: @soledar10, пожалуйста, перенесите своё решение в ответ, чтобы пользователи с такой же проблемой его лучше видели а также дабы я смог Вас плюсануть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, пихать `br` в список — это неправильно, и так делать не надо. Следует использовать `margin-top` для интересующих элементов списка.

Во-вторых, когда ты добавляешь `br`, номера элементов смещаются. Теперь `li` не 1, 2 и 3, а 1, 3 и 4. Можно либо перенумеровать индексы в CSS-правиле, либо заменить `li:nth-child` на `li:nth-of-type`, чтобы считались только `li`, но не `br`.

Comment: Лучше `li:nth-of-type` всегда использовать, ибо после вставки между элементами списка картинок тегом `<img>`, номера маркеров также смещаются.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, всегда надо не пихать в список всякою фигню вместо элементов. Он не для этого.

Comment: А если элементы имеют относительно большой размер?

Comment: @СашаЧерных, а на что это влияет?

Comment: В каждом пункте списка много текста. Для удобства восприятия куча текста разделяется на абзацы, вставляются картинки, используются вложенные списки и т. д.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, ну так эти элементы надо вкладывать в li. Или вообще отказаться от ul/li и использовать div'ы (и/или section'ы и другие подобные теги).

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать `br` между `li` - валидатор выдаст ошибку

> Element br not allowed as child of element ol in this context.
>   (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Для отступов между `li` используйте `margin-top` (`margin-bottom`)

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: bisque;
  color: crimson;
}

.list {
  line-height: 1.5;
  list-style-type: none;  
}
.list li{
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.list li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.list li:nth-child(1):before {content: '4.';}
.list li:nth-child(2):before {content: '14.';}
.list li:nth-child(3):before {content: '7.';}
```

```html
Бессонница ненавистна не сама по себе, а обязательно обуяющей вас с рассветом усталостью, аннигилирующей способности мыслить и радоваться. Натянув капюшон, я старался не отягощать серое вещество размышлениями, уповая сохранить хоть какие-то силы. У поребрика близ палатки шавермы сайд- и фронт-киками всадили в рёбра женщине, на фоне полёта насекомых — вылитых фей — зарядили непосредственно по моему мениску.
  <ol class="list">
    <li>В российских реалиях полноценно это светит исключительно при обладании достаточной суммой на счету. Оптимальный вариант ради горизонтальной доски с ножками и относительного покоя — заплатить за кучу лишних услуг хостелам. В том числе выбравшись из дому: номера общежития на 10—20 обитателей, сдобренного запахом пропавших пельменей и отборным матом. Неужели никому не нравится подыматься спозаранку на службу при бодром расположении духа, что в подлунной тиши не заткнётся орущий телевизор?</li>
    <li>Саша Мечта</li>
    <li>И История</li>
  </ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ради кастомных числовых значений списка достаточно использовать атрибут value тега li

```
<ol>
  <li value="4">В российских реалиях полноценно это светит...</li>
  <li value="14">Саша Мечта</li>
  <li value="7">И История</li>
</ol>
```

Если нужны иные, не числовые значения, или числовые, но содержащие точки, то достаточно добавить такой стиль:

```
ol[type="value"] > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
ol[type="value"] > li::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4em;
  left: -4.25em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(value);
}

<ol type="value">
  <li value="4.">В российских реалиях полноценно это светит...</li>
  <li value="14.">Саша Мечта</li>
  <li value="7.">И История</li>
  <li value="7.133">И еще </li>
</ol>
```

Примеры:

```html
<p>Бессонница ненавистна не сама по себе</p>
<ol>
  <li value="4">В российских реалиях полноценно это...</li>
  <li value="14">Саша Мечта</li>
  <br />
  <li value="7">И История</li>
</ol>
```

```css
ol[type="value"] > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
ol[type="value"] > li::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4em;
  left: -4.25em;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(value);
}
```

```html
<p>Бессонница ненавистна не сама по себе, а обязательно обуяющей вас с рассветом усталостью, аннигилирующей способности мыслить и радоваться.</p>
<ol type="value">
  <li value="4.">В российских реалиях полноценно это светит исключительно при обладании достаточной суммой на счету.</li>
  <br />
  <li value="14.">Саша Мечта</li>
  <br />
  <li value="7.">И История</li>
  <li value="9.876">И еще история</li>
</ol>
```